# Determine any number in this sequence

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving a maths problem and have noticed that the answers so far are 6, 10, 15, 21. This would make the pattern: add 4, add 5, add 6, add 7. I.e. you are adding 1 more than the previous time.

I want to make an equation/algorithm so that any number could be determined using the pattern stated above.

This is what I have so far

tn = 6
tn+1 = 6 + 4
tn+2 = 6 + 4 + 5
tn+3 = 6 + 4 + 5 + 6

6 is the starting number.

Comment: It's interesting that you chose "t" to represent the function as it is exactly [the triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula), shifted a bit. You can replace "n" with "n+2" to get the desired result.

Comment: that's $(n+2)(n+3)/2$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the sequence of the sum of natural numbers until $n$.

You can use the *Small Gauss sum* to compute your sequence:
$$a_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
This starts with $1$, $a_3$ is your starting value $6$.

If you want your starting value to be $6$, just replace $n$ with $n+2$.